# Add query parameters at dstore/Rest request

Tags: javascript, dojo, dstore

I have a dstore/Rest instance like this:

```
const entries = new Rest({ target: '/rest/entries' })
```

And I need to add a token as query parameter for every PUT/POST request, so url for my PUT/POST request should look like this:

```
'/rest/entries/100500?token=some_token'
```

Is there in dstore/Rest any convinient way to do this? Or maybe set header before each request and place token there. Anyway, my problem is to build correct request when I call

```
entries.add({id: 100500, value: 'someValue'})
```

**Update:**

I figured out, that Rest.add accepts two arguments - object and options and managed to add token in headers:

```
entries.add(entry, {
            headers: {
                Token: token
            }
        })
```

But I'm still curious about query parameters.

Comment: the headers method does'nt sweet you , do you want to attach token just on instantion of the  `dstore/Rest` ?

Comment: Headers are ok, but I have to add token as querystring parameter. I've found a solution that works for me already. I just extended Rest class with setToken method and append token using dojo/aspect before put/add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find following solution for me:

```
lang.extend(Rest, {
    setToken: function(token) {
        this.token = token

        aspect.after(this, '_getTarget', function(target) {
            if (this.token) {
                target += '?token=' + this.token
                this.token = undefined
            }
            return target
        })


        aspect.before(this, 'add', function() {
            if (this.token) {
                this.target += '?token=' + this.token
                this.token = undefined
            }
        })

        return this
    }
})
```

And I use it like this:

```
entries.setToken(token).add(data)
```

But I'm not sure that it's a good way to accomplish my task.

Comment: i'd extend Rest adding in your method into it's own object (file) so you to make it a bit more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

I think Iheriting the dstore/Rest , by creating your custom `MyRest.js` class an adding headers in constructor will help you to pass token in constrictor then , do operations without using headers each time.

You new class should look like :

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dstore/Rest',
    'dojo/_base/lang',
], function (declare, Rest) {

    return declare(Rest, {
 //                  ^
 //                  |
 // inheritence -----
        constructor: function(headers) {  // headers object : {Token: token};
            this.inherited(arguments); // like super() in poo
            this.headers = this.headers || {};
            lang.mixin(this.headers, headers || {});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about doing it this way.